# Hello Im wondering if anybody can help me figure out how to keep the edge from stretching while using the mirror modifier?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, vertices, faces

[image]

Hello Im wondering if anybody can help me figure out how to keep the edge from stretching  while using the mirror modifier?

Comment: hello, it's not clear what's happening, are you looking for the Clipping option (in your modifier)?

Comment: Your modifier is both bisecting and flipped along the X axis meaning all geometry in the positive X space will be overwritten by the geometry in the negative X space mirrored. If you want it to stop stretching, check "Clipping" in the modifier settings and move the extended geometry back to the X = 0 plane